# Facebook like button doesn't show up on website

Tags: html, facebook, api, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

I used the HTML5 and IFRAME options listed on the developers facebook pages, but it doesn't seem to work at all. 
The weird thing is that it works on a blank page without any content. Is there something that can conflict with it?

Conflict Page: http://helbreathempire.com/
Blank Page: http://helbreathempire.com/include/test.html

Comment: On line 41 of [style.css](http://helbreathempire.com/styles.css) you have have `display: none;` for your iframe (hence it not being displayed ;) ) - `iframe { border: 0 none; display: none; }`. Either delete `display: none` or change it to `display: block`

Comment: @MyHeadHurts, this question can't be resolved until you make your comment a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you follow this option to add the button using HTML5:

1) Place, immediately below the tag  the following code to load the Facebook Javascript SDK:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

2) In the place where you want the button to appear, put the code:

```
<div class = "fb-like"
  data-href = "http://helbreathempire.com/"
  data-width = "500"
  data-layout = "standard" data-action = "like"
  data-show-faces = "true"
  data-share = "true"> </ div>
```

Hopefully this time will be easier!